# How to convert Unicode in a field

Tags: text

I imported German text through Feed Me, but the special characters show up as unicode characters:

> “Ich interessiere mich sehr f\u00fcr Alte Musik”

I tried a filter when outputting the text, but no success: `|convert_encoding("ISO-8859-1","UNICODE-1-1")`

However, would prefer to have the text be readable in the backend as well not just on the frontend with the filter.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If this were PHP, you'd need to run that through [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to get it to convert.

I don't think there's an equivalent way to do that from Twig, but you could write a simple plugin that added an `htmlentitydecode` [Twig filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/extending-twig.html) to pull it off.